# java lambda map().collect(Collectors.toList()) compile error

Tags: java, lambda, type-inference

when i compile my  code, it report compile error.
I think it will run but report error!
Why it wrong  when **map()** phase contains Generic field ,and set value,

** error message:
java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to
java.util.List<normal.BaseWork.B>**

```
    public class B {
        private Long id;
        private Map<String, Long> wk;
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Map<String, Long> getWk() {
            return wk;
        }

        public void setWk(Map<String, Long> wk) {
            this.wk = wk;
        }
    }
    public static class A {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<A> details = new ArrayList<>(12);
        List<B> collect = details.stream()
                .map(detail -> {
                    B b = new B();
                    b.setId(12L);
                    Map mp = new HashMap(3);
                    mp.put("12",new Object());
                    b.setWk(mp);
                    return b;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Don't use raw types for `Map` and `HashMap`.

Comment: Yep, add generic to Map and HashMap, if somewhere you don't use it, all other generics will be dropped

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, for reasons other than the error message you give. If I modify it slightly to make it compile, it doesn't give the error message. Please give a complete, reproducible code example.

Comment: Exactly what others said. **Don't use raw types**. Always provide the necessary type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

B.wk has the type Map<String, Long>.

In the stream.map you call b.setWk with a Map that has no generic type set.

This will cause the compiler to see that your new Object() doesn't match the Long type that B.wk wants for its values.